# This is related to npm not being able to download a dependency

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

```
C:\Users\Manoj\Desktop\accounts>npm install intro.js --save
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/swimlane/dragula.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-26T07_47_10_601Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Manoj\Desktop\accounts>
```

I'm trying to install intro.js in my angular project but when I give npm install intro.js --save command I'm getting the above error. I'm new to this npm installation.Thanks for helping on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't have [git](https://git-scm.com/).

Make sure you have `git` installed on your machine, because `npm` tries to download using `git`

Comment: Yes I just figured it out hat I need to install git. Thanks for the help V. Sambor