# npm install -g angular/cli not working on command line

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, npm-install

Node.js v18.16.1

C:\Users\SunSoft>node -v
v18.16.1

C:\Users\SunSoft>npm install -g angular/cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SunSoft\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-23T05_42_15_263Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\SunSoft>

I was trying to install angular using command line interface.. when i try to install it I couldn't install it. I am using Node 19.16.1

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60863349/6513921

Answer (score 0):

Open Powershell as an administrative privilege and run the following the command:

```ps
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```